# How to populate html table with info from list in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to populate, in my django application, my table from `base.html` with the results from urlparse.py (this returns a list of 20 URLs from a site).

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode

# Create your models here.
```

urlparse.py

```
import HTMLParser, urllib2

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):
    site_list = []

    def reset(self):
        HTMLParser.HTMLParser.reset(self)
        self.in_a = False
        self.next_link_text_pair = None
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag=='a':
            for name, value in attrs:
                if name=='href':
                    self.next_link_text_pair = [value, '']
                    self.in_a = True
                    break
    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.in_a: self.next_link_text_pair[1] += data
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag=='a':
            if self.next_link_text_pair is not None:
                if self.next_link_text_pair[0].startswith('/siteinfo/'):
                    self.site_list.append(self.next_link_text_pair[1])
            self.next_link_text_pair = None
            self.in_a = False

if __name__=='__main__':
    p = MyHTMLParser()
    p.feed(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.alexa.com/topsites/global').read())
    print p.site_list[:20]
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    #url(r'^$', 'signups.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                          document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, RequestContext

# Create your views here.
```

base.html

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Rank</th>
                <th>Website</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Something</td>
                <td>{{site.urls}}</td><!--What to put here ?-->
                <td>something</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Can anybody point me into the right direction ? How do I parse the results from urlparse.py into the second `<td>` tag and what modification will appear in other files ? (forms,views,urls).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the list of urls to the template and use the [`{% for %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#for) tag to loop them.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'myapp.views.top_urls', name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

**views.py**

```
def top_urls(request):
    p = MyHTMLParser()
    p.feed(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.alexa.com/topsites/global').read())
    urls = p.site_list[:20]
    print urls
    return render(request, 'top_urls.html', {'urls': urls})
```

**top_urls.html**

```
...
<tbody>
    {% for url in urls %}
        <tr>
            <td>Something</td>
            <td>{{ url }}</td>
            <td>something</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
...
```

Comment: thanks for this fast answer. Unfortunately, nothing seems to happen. The table is still empty. Any hints ?

Comment: What do you mean by "table is still empty"?  Table has no rows in the `<tbody>`?  Or `<td>` with url is empty?

Comment: I mean there are no populated rows in my table. It just says: `No data available in table`. So, the urls are not parsed into the table as they should.

Comment: Add `print urls` as in my updated answer and check the output of the devsever's console.  I suspect that the `p.site_list` is empty.

Comment: I cleared my cache and there is another problem: `NameError at /`.`global name 'MyHTMLParser' is not defined`

Comment: You should import the `MyHTMLParser` in the `views.py`.  Something like `from .urlparse import MyHTMLParser`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74063/discussion-between-alexander-and-catavaran).